# TypeScript type for a function with a return type specified by an input parameter

Tags: typescript

I’m trying to specify a TypeScript type for a function that takes an `input` and an optional `outputType` parameter which determines the return type. If no `outputType` is specified the return type matches `typeof input`. The return value may also be a `Promise` of that type.

For example,

```
type Decrypter = (options: {
  input: string | Buffer | stream.Readable;
  outputType?: "string" | "buffer" | "stream" | undefined;
}) => X | Promise<X>;
```

Where `X` would be `string`, `Buffer`, or `stream.Readable` depending on the value of `outputType`, or the same type as `options["input"]` if `outputType` is `undefined`.

I feel like there is something that can be done with generics, `extends`, and possibly `infer`, but I can’t quite get the right incantation!

Any ideas?

Below is an example of a basic implementation:

```
const decrypter: Decrypter = async ({ input, outputType }) => {
  let encrypted: string;
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    encrypted = input;
    outputType ??= "string";
  } else if (Buffer.isBuffer(input)) {
    encrypted = input.toString("utf8");
    outputType ??= "buffer";
  } else if (Readable.isReadable(input)) {
    const buffers = [];
    for await (const buffer of input as Readable) {
      buffers.push(buffer);
    }
    encrypted = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString("utf8");
    outputType ??= "stream";
  } else {
    throw new Error("Invalid input");
  }

  const decrypted = encrypted.split("").reverse().join("");

  switch (outputType) {
    case "string":
      return decrypted;
    case "buffer":
      return Buffer.from(decrypted);
    case "stream":
      return Readable.from(decrypted);
    default:
      throw new Error("Invalid outputType");
  }
};
```

I’m using Node.js v18.4.0, TypeScript v4.7.4.

Comment: when someone passes `"buffer"` for the outputType do you want the resulting type to be `"buffer"` or `Buffer` ?

Comment: @TobiasS. `Buffer`.

Comment: @TobiasS. So `outputType` of `"string"` => return type `string`, `"buffer"` => `Buffer`, `"stream"` => `stream.Readable`.

If `outputType` is `undefined` then the return type will be `string`/`Buffer`/`stream.Readable` to match the type of `input`.

For any of these listed return types it could also be a `Promise` to that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing we need is a map which maps from the string literal type to the return type.

```
type TypeMap = {
  string: string
  buffer: Buffer
  stream: stream.Readable
}
```

For both `input` and `output` we add the generic types `I` and `O` to capture the type of the object passed to the function. We also constrain both generic types to their respective allowed inputs. We add `never` as the default type for `O` if a type for `outputType` was not provided.

```
type Decrypter = <
  I extends TypeMap[keyof TypeMap], 
  O extends keyof TypeMap = never
>(options: {
  input: I;
  outputType?: O;
}) => DecryptorReturn<O, I>;
```

For the return type we check if any type was provided for `O`. If yes, we can use the `TypeMap` to lookup the type.

```
type DecryptorReturn<O extends keyof TypeMap, I> = [O] extends [never]
  ? I | Promise<I> 
  : TypeMap[O] | Promise<TypeMap[O]>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=11&ssc=37&pln=9&pc=1#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAOxgWzAZwA4wkzAFwXUQG9hErFCBPbJAJTBhBgCMokBecxdgFyIicAJbIA5ogC+AbmDTgdBogBCAVwBmmsHES8yiGEJHipi4JeVIAIpDj1CAezjNC6uMgA8AeURgAD0IwZBBMRABrMFonTUQAFXowAFkYbAAaRABJAD59RABtHwBdfyCQsMLkMAA3XWLKRAB+bMQAH0QABTgnNFFMMC9cxEahRIZU7CLSju7e-sHxlLTpnKskhKTJ-IoqU0kTYjNG9i0dOCENbV1GkRY0Q5I0ADpmVg4uBUslDbsIB2wwT0vCGZWCoXCS0mBSiMTiULSxUyfkC4MqsNimwmaXy1TqcByAAonIDRE5kJghLtEOJsOpCEIsvIqE56XTCEsmkIfPJpABKfR5P4A5yuMDuTy+TK5eTfYAQclERCaZBCYWOXQ7aRGcIwZC0SwKimERAITAARnyKsJhlp9KEACIOBAHTI+cAAPQe6iIAB6TUNipNZoATFbkDaach2Y7nQ7MqzCOylo7Ttc4K7+Z7vdR-UA)

---

Now some tests to see if it's working:

```
const fn: Decrypter = {} as any

const res1 = fn({ input: "abc" })
//    ^? const res1: "abc" | Promise<"abc">

const res2 = fn({ input: "abc", outputType: "buffer" })
//    ^? const res2: Buffer | Promise<Buffer>
```

Looks good to me.

---

When you writing functions with complex generic types, TypeScript will always have problems understanding the logic of your function implementation. For example, you try to assign a `string` to `outputType`. But since `outputType` is of type `O` TypeScript will net let you assign anything to it.

So have some short-comings when trying to type the function itself. First of all, I would give `input` and `outputType` explicit types which are not generic so that you can assign things to them.

```
(async ({ input, outputType }: {input: TypeMap[keyof TypeMap], outputType: keyof TypeMap}) => { ... }
```

TypeScript will now have problems with assigning this function to the type `Decrypter` because it is not generic. I would use a simple type assertion to silence this error.

```
const decrypter: Decrypter = (async ({ input, outputType }: {input: TypeMap[keyof TypeMap], outputType: keyof TypeMap}) => {
  /* ... */
}) as Decrypter
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=57&pc=16#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAOxgWzAZwA4wkzAFwXUQG9hErFCBPbJAJTBhBgCMokBecxdgFyIicAJbIA5ogC%20AbmDTgdBogBCAVwBmmsHES8yiGEJHipi4JeVIAIpDj1CAezjNC6uMgA8AeURgAD0IwZBBMRABrMFonTUQAFXowAFkYbAAaRABJAD59RD9A4NDw5DAAN11KRAB%20bMQAH0QABTgnNFFMMC9cxGqhRIZU7ABtHwBdRpa2jq6vQZS0sfGcqySEpOH8iipTSRNiM2r2LR04IQ1tKt3iFjQDkjQAOmZWDi4FSyV1uwgHbGCel4PX8QRCYQ2QyWURicQWw3GmUKYJKkWisUhi2w%20TKlTgOQAFE4AaInMhMEIdohxNh1IQhFl5FQnHTaYQFjUhD55NIAJT6PK-f7OVxgdyeXyZXLySwQMlERDgP6OXRCIUqoGIAkwTC0ZAQLWGGl0zIswhshYySnG%20mY4YjGEY%20FpRGIM0WpJCR1wzZpPkC8jVLiEfz64VgEAPMxM6lxAnWDE2-TcXgAIj2ElT-KpVBCyoBEfyNpjzNZdMtNRqaYzqZj0n8UC6sa1lzOT06rd0BJtvOz1VzYZVICLyDZT2cAGVDpICam6ZoABxZktusvs9aVtMnK5wWvVetgRtIURx15sThgduYM-vMDd0d03uB6iIOXkkPbs7hXgjcYrzQuEYADuMCiCGBJvgqn66G6cRJjqiA3hefYvlQ0FwJgTy0pgAAWBLobyK6KC%20ebhsOvCdnATxvhAMCEPhpy6JgvLjk4U5iDOc6EIuy79qu5rlhuVaIOmtzoHuVAHkez7UIQOFtEBKBgIpACicBtHAs5ZMg5QwFAojDjavGSZYVCQSGSpkfkpFDk8OD6fRqZZk8CB4l0BIsQAVk44izrx1SYEBYEQDhWruoJDAodQtFNqJHGZgIfFUAg4rIIq9hDiuMVIKm6GpolqGIClHhpZRTyaDMBKWUOhF8dlIkiHc%20VJUVYolYhLDnlw5WVdVBYgLVL7gJoMDqFA9ItXJClKap6kuFpOl6QZ-EegwxkyAo-IIeqBZwLK8ohggmAAIz5JoyAEkaD62qmHAQKmMi8sAAD0z0vgAejU%203vq1mAAExnRdV1skIt3sPdpprgsoN5Y9L1vdQn1AA)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I can confirm that your edit does work. I think ultimately I may revise the API and have a separate function for each output type so I can avoid having to coerce the implementation to fit the type given the limitations with generics.